# Mongoose - Remove all documents found using a promise

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to bulk delete comments as a document rather than a model as i want to later use the pre-hook remove method.

The below command finds multiple documents that satisfy the query and attempts to delete each comment one by one. After all are removed the next() function is called if there is any error during the stage it should catch it.

```
Comment.find({'moment': this._id})
    .then(((comments) => Promise.each(comments, (comment) => comment.remove()))
    .then(next())
    .catch(next()));
```

However this gives me an error and not delete the comment

> "TypeError: (intermediate value).then is not a function"

Comment: not sure if related, but afaik you should call exec on find to get a full promise: `comment.find({ ... }).exec()`. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: i get Promise.each is not a functin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use native promises and i could achieve this using the Promise.all

```
Comment.find({'moment': this._id})
    .then((comments) => {
        Promise.all(comments.forEach((comment) => comment.remove()))
            .then(next());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   .then(() => next())
    .catch(() => next()));
```

Or this (with error handling)

```
   .then(() => next())
    .catch(next);
```